# Compare two lists and replace values in list one with values in list 2

Tags: python

I have two lists.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,0,4,5,6,3,6,0,5,6,8,0,3]
b = [1,2, None,4,5,4,5,6,3,6,7,5,6,8,4, None]
```

I want a resulting list like this.

```
new_list = [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,3,6,7,5,6,8,4,3]
```

List b is only replacing the 0's in list a and not touching the other elements for example the None is not being replaced.

How can I get about doing this? 
Thanks in advance. Please do let me know if you need any other information.

I have tried the following and it does not work.

```
_ = dict(zip(a,b))
for k,v in _.items():
   if k == 0:
       a = a.replace(k,v)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: - = dict(zip(a,b))
for k,v in _.items():
    if k == 0:
        a = a.replace(k,v)

Comment: For `a = [0, 1, 0]` and `b = [None, 2, 3]`, what do you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip` and a simple list comprehension to generate a new list by picking elements of `a` if they're not 0 or elements of `b` if the corresponding `a` element is zero:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 0, 5, 6, 8, 0, 3]
b = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, None]

result = [y if x == 0 else x for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(result)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, 3]
```

Comment: For `a = [0, 1, 0]` and `b = [None, 2, 3]`, result will be `[None, 1, 3]`...is that what the OP wants?

Comment: I think so. If you don't want `None`, you can change the condition to `y if x == 0 and y is not None ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
out = []
for ea, eb in zip(a, b): 
  res = ea 
  # if element in a is 0 and corresponding element in b is not None
  if ea == 0 and eb:
    res = eb 
  out.append(res)

assert out == [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,3,6,7,5,6,8,4,3]
```

And for `a = [0, 1, 0]` and `b = [None, 2, 3]` this will generate

```
out == [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Wheres your explanation?

Comment: The code is self-explanatory, yet added a comment at the risk of stating the obvious

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
a = [1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 0, 9]
b = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6, None, 8, 9]

k = 0  # Counter
c = [0] * len(a)  # Creating the 'c' list
for n in a:  # Reading 'a' list
    if n != 0: 
        c[k] = a[k]  # Copying 'a' list objects, when 'n' != 0, in 'c' list
    else:
        c[k] = b[k]  # Copying 'b' list objects, when 'n' == 0, in 'c' list
    k = k + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `enumerate` + a loop + indexing:

```
l=[i for i,v in enumerate(a) if v==0]
for i in l:
    a[i]=b[i]
```

And now:

```
print(a)
```

Is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 6, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, 3]
```

Comment: You are effectively iterating over the length of the list twice to achieve the end result. That's inefficient.